# Composing urls in a subform loop

Tags: subform

It works but it is not great.
It's about getting the fields of a subform to display the urls and other fields in a loop

Today I have
PHP code:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->item->jcfields[111]->value)): ?>

    <br /><b><span><i class="fa fa-link fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Pros des films :</b>

        <?php
        $field_value = json_decode($this->item->jcfields[111]->rawvalue);
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        $factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();
        $lang="fr";
        $item_id="159";
    ?>

    <?php foreach ($field_value as $value): ?>
        <?php
            $article_id = $value->field110;
            $table = $factory->createTable('Article', 'Table');
            $table->load($article_id);
            $item_catid = $table->catid;
            echo HTMLHelper::link(
                Route::_("/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id={$article_id}&catid={$item_catid}&Itemid={$item_id}&lang={$lang}"),
                $table->alias
            );    
         ?>
     <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php endif ?>
```

The rendering is :
Pros des films : kamea-meah meteore-films​

Le code HTML est :
Code HTML:

```
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp; id=119&amp;catid=21&amp;Itemid=159&amp;lang=fr">kamea-meah</a>
<a href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp; id=122&amp;catid=21&amp;Itemid=159&amp;lang=fr">meteore-films</a>​
```

1/ how to have a SEF url ?
I have set the SEF url in the general config

2/ how to add another subform field and formatting?

> Film pros : kamea-meah (production) - meteore-films (direction)

DEBUG

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($field_value), '</pre>';
```

=>

```
stdClass Object
(
[row0] => stdClass Object
(
[field110] => 119
[field112] => Array
(
[0] => film_rea
)

)

[row1] => stdClass Object
(
[field110] => 122
)

)​
```

I'll need to retrieve the term "director from the value of "film_rea" custom field

Comment: Hi
I have made good progress but I am missing one last point concerning the router.